# type incompatibility for generic arrays

Tags: delphi, generics

The problem is best explained when you look at some sample code (I've deleted all unnecessary code):

```
program XE8GenericArrayTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TArrayUtilCls<T: class> = class
  public
    class procedure AddArray<U: T>(var Arr_: TArray<T>; ArrayToAdd: TArray<U>);
    class procedure MergeArrays(var Arr_: TArray<T>; ArrayToAdd: TArray<T>);
  end;
  TBaseCls = class
  end;
  TChild = class(TBaseCls)
  end;

{ TArrayUtilCls<T> }

class procedure TArrayUtilCls<T>.AddArray<U>(var Arr_: TArray<T>;
  ArrayToAdd: TArray<U>);
begin
  // ... some logic to merge the arrays
end;

class procedure TArrayUtilCls<T>.MergeArrays(var Arr_: TArray<T>;
  ArrayToAdd: TArray<T>);
begin
  // THE FOLLOWING CODE LINE DOES NOT COMPILE
  // E2515 Type parameter 'U' is not compatible with type 'T'
  AddArray<T>(Arr_, ArrayToAdd);
end;

var
  ArrBase: TArray<TBaseCls>;
  ArrChildren: TArray<TChild>;
begin
  // ... allocate memory
  TArrayUtilCls<TBaseCls>.AddArray<TChild>(ArrBase, ArrChildren);
end.
```

The class `TArrayUtilCls` contains a method to add an array of subtypes to an array of base types `AddArray`- this works fine.

Now I also want to add a method that does the same for 2 arrays which are of the same type: `MergeArrays`.

I think it should simply work to call the `AddArray<T>` method, since `U` must extend from `T` anyway: But Delphi gives me a compile error (see comment in the source-code).

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/1687755/62576 will help

Comment: @KenWhite Nope, the question you linked to is related to generic variance. This one just seems to be a compiler bug with constraints.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand why this code would be rejected. Do all compiler versions do so?

Comment: I mean **cannot** rather than **can**, obviously. Seattle rejects it too. Submit a bug report.

Comment: I've created a bugreport: [RSP-13641](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13641)